# Is there any possible way to recover JPG images from a specific period of time?

Tags: data-recovery

Yesterday, during data transmission to an external hard drive, all data was lost due to unexpected HDD crash. I've tried to use PhotoRec for a specific partition, and it retrieved over 50 000 images, nevertheless, most of the obtained files are older than 3-5 months.

In advance, thank you for your help. :)

Comment: [This](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/After_Using_PhotoRec) provides some Info about sorting after Photorec Recovery .

Comment: @tijybba You might want to post an answer based on this comment.

Comment: @EliahKagan- Thanks for suggestion , i am not good with coding :( , so in this case i would Urge you to post an answer on that , if you wish.

Comment: Tijybba, thank you for sharing this helpful source. 
I've managed to retrieve files much quicker. :)

Comment: I use [`sort-pictures`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/sort-pictures.1.html) from `recoverjpeg` tool which nicely sorts images in date directories. The files need to be renamed to `image?????*.jpg` format, see the manpage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case your JPG files have EXIF data stored this can easily be accomplished with

#### [jhead](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/jhead) [image: Install jhead]

Command line tool to manipulate EXIF data, and to touch the timestamp or rename a jpg file according to the EXIF data stored within the file.

```
jhead -ft unnamed.jpg  # to touch the time
jhead -n%Y%m%d-%H%M%S unnamed.jpg # to rename in this format YYYYMMDD-hhmmss
```

#### [exiv2](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/exiv2) [image: Install exiv2]

Another, similar tool will also manipulate and use EXIf data from other file fomats including:

> Supported formats are JPEG, TIFF, PNG,  JP2,  Adobe  DNG, Canon CRW, Canon THM, Nikon NEF, Pentax PEF and XMP sidecar files. Read-only support is currently available for PSD and several TIFF-based RAW  formats:  Canon  CR2, Fujifilm RAF, Minolta MRW, Olympus ORF, Sony ARW and Sony SR2. <sup>Manpage [exiv2](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jaunty/man1/exiv2.1.html)</sup>

```
exiv2 rename unnamed.jpg # will rename to YYYYMMDD_hhmmss.jpg
```

#### Shotwell

Shotwell Photo Manager is installed by default and can sort images according to their EXIF data:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can recover all images with the method you want. After this, you can sort them by date with your favorite data explorer (for example `nautilus`).

Answer (score 0):

I use [`sort-pictures`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/sort-pictures.1.html) from `recoverjpeg` tool, it sorts pictures nicely into date directories.

> Running sort-pictures will scan the current directory for files named after  the  template `image?????*.jpg`  (image  followed  by  at  least five characters followed by .jpg).  A new hardlink will be created for each file in one of the following directories:
>
> - `invalid` The picture is an invalid JFIF file.
> - `small` The picture size is less than 100,000 bytes.
> - `undated` Sort-pictures was unable to determine the date of  the  picture  from  the  exif tags.
> - `YYYY-MM-DD` A directory representing the date at which the picture was taken.

Install from [`universe`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository):

```bsh
# enable universe repo if not already
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
# install
sudo apt install recoverjpeg
```

Something like this should do the job:

```bsh
n=0
# loop jpg-files from recup-dir (the ones starting with `f` are "full" size
for f in recup*/f*.jpg; do
    # mv the file to a subdir of the current working dir "./sorted"
    # renaming to image??????.jpg
    mv "$f" sorted/image$(printf "%06d\n" $n).jpg
    # print and increment counter
    printf '\r%d' $n;
    n=$((n+1))
done
echo
# go into "sorted" directory and run `sort-pictures`
cd sorted && sort-pictures
```

Then, you have nicely sorted images :-)

Comment: This will move the files one by one which will work fine, but I'm sure there is a nicer solution renaming many files in one go, but no time to test something now...